# WPF C# - Combobox data to number for database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, combobox

I've set the combobox data in the c# code, I would like to write to the database with a number rather than the text in the combobox; for instance I would like to have:

1 - View Only = 1

2 - Basic User = 2

3 - Supervisor = 3

4 - Administrator = 4

5 - Super User = 5

I've no idea how to do this. Below is what I've got so far.

```
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... A List.
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    data.Add("1 - View Only");
    data.Add("2 - Basic User");
    data.Add("3 - Supervisor");
    data.Add("4 - Administrator");
    data.Add("5 - Super User");

    // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
    comboBox.ItemsSource = data;

    // ... Make the first item selected.
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... Get the ComboBox.
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    // ... Set SelectedItem as Window Title.
    string value = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;
    this.Title = "Selected: " + value;
}
```

So to sum up my ideal outcome - When someone selects "1 - View Only" from the combobox it sets the user level in the database to 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For something simplistic, you can use `comboBox.SelectedIndex + 1`, but that will break down if the order of your items changes somehow.

For something slightly more elaborate, you could do the following:

```
namespace ComboBoxExampleWPF
{
    class UserLevel
    {
        public UserLevel(int level, string description)
        {
            Level = level;
            Description = description;
        }

        public int Level { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }

        // This controls how it shows up in the comboBox
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Level.ToString() + " - " + Description;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<UserLevel> list = new List<UserLevel>()
            {
                new UserLevel(1, "View Only"),
                new UserLevel(2, "Basic User"),
                new UserLevel(3, "Supervisor"),
                new UserLevel(4, "Administrator"),
                new UserLevel(5, "Super User")
            };

            comboBox1.ItemsSource = list;
            comboBox1.SelectionChanged += comboBox1_SelectionChanged;
        }

        void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... Get the ComboBox.
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

            // ... Set SelectedItem as Window Title.
            UserLevel value = comboBox.SelectedItem as UserLevel;
            this.Title = "Selected: " + value.ToString();

            SetUserLevel(value);
        }

        private void SetUserLevel(UserLevel ul)
        {
            // _myDatabase.SetUserLevel(ul.Level);
        }
    }
}
```